# ¿Cómo filtro peliculas por género desde api omdb?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, npm

Estoy intentando filtrar la data por género (drama, comedia, terror, etc) desde API omdb, pero hasta ahora no lo consigo, me podrían ayudar, o tal vez conozcan algún otro API que me permita hacerlo. Este es mi codigo de js:

```
function apiCall(movie) {
  $.getJSON('https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + movie + 
'&apikey=3a181f1c').then(function(response) {
console.log(response);
var title = response.Title;
var image = response.Poster;
genre = response.Genre;
plot = response.Plot;

var arrGenres = genre.split(', ');
console.log(arrGenres);

for (var i = 0; i < arrGenres.length; i++) {
  if (arrGenres[i] === 'Comedy') {
    console.log('Es comedia');
  } else if (arrGenres[i] === 'Drama') {
    console.log('Es drama');
  } else if (arrGenres[i] === 'Action') {
    console.log('Es acción');
  }
}

if (title !== 'N/A') {
  $('.container-genre').append('<p>' + title + '</p>');
  $('#movie').append($('.container-genre'));
}
});
}
$('#searchForm').on('submit', function() {
  var text = $('#titleFld').val();
  apiCall(text);
});
```

Comment: No veo ningún problema con el código... ¿qué es lo que te falta hacer? ¿en qué está fallando? ... Lo probé en https://jsfiddle.net/qhy6z3jp/ y muestra en consola el género sin problema ... Probá agregando `return false` en el submit, para que no envíe el formulario.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que ese código solo me jala las películas que yo escribo en el buscador, las jala por título, pero yo quiero hacer un filtro por genero de películas, pero no se como recorrer la data del API para obtener solo los géneros :,(

Comment: La API que estás usando entiendo que devuelve una sola película, no varias, y no tiene ningún parámetro para buscar por géneros (al menos no que esté documentado en la web)... ¿Es eso?

Comment: Hay otro método que es usando el parámetro `?s=titulo`, que devuelve más de una película, pero no devuelve el género... Entonces deberías hacer 1 llamada así para obtener todas las películas y sucesivas llamadas por cada película para obtener los géneros.

Comment: holis,estoy usando la api por primera vez y me gustaria saber si pudiste solucionarlo o conseguir una alternativa
estoy pensando hacer algo como lo que decis pero justamente me esta costando